# Drag down formula from multiple sheets on one sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have 19 Sheets on each sheet in cell B17 I have a result.
On my first sheet I have cell numbers from 1-19.

In my first sheet I type in cell one the Formula `='sheet 1'!$B$17`. I have the number in cell `B17` mirrored.

Now I want to drag down from one to 19, currently it always takes sheet one instead of a continuation `='Sheet2'!$B$17` etc. How do I do that?
How do I have the sheet continues but the cell `B17` remaining?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a formula (even the `&` for concatenation) to form a reference, then you need to use the INDIRECT() formula.  This alerts the Excel interpreter to resolve the formula to determine the reference, and *then* pass that reference to the interpreter as if it was typed.

Let's say you have the numbers 1 through 19 in column A, cells A2 through A20.  In that case, you could type this in B2 and copy it down:

`=INDIRECT( "'sheet " & A2 & "'!$B$17" )`

You gotta carefully keep track of the various single and double quotes, and the embedded space between "sheet" and the number, if needed.  It's easy to get off track when you are typing it all.